# How to stop the browser showing previous page content

Tags: laravel, flash-message

I am working on laravel project and using sweet alerts for the success messages once the success message show and I go the form page and come back without form submit it shows the success message again.
How can I stop doing this?
In my search, I found that it's not laravel error its error of the browser trying to get previous page content.

Comment: What's the trigger for success message?

Comment: show you error and some code

Comment: @AdrianEdyPratama : I'm using this:
Validation skip due to less space in comments 

public function store(Request $request, $id)
    {
          Efterat::create($request->all());
        Alert::success('Framgång', 'Framgångsrikt skickat'); 
        if (Auth::user()->role == "clients")
        {
            return redirect()->to('om/'.$id);
        }else{
            return redirect()->to('instalningar/'.$id);
        
        }
    }

Comment: @Hamelraj
I put the code in the comment the issue is that i have to go back on another page when form submit. you can see that at the end redirects. so how i can make it possible